# How to match an element whose type's namespace is xsd:string

Tags: xslt

How do I specify a match for an element whose type attribute is in xsd: namespace? For example:

```
<enitityID maxOccurs="0" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
```

I tried

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri(@type)= 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema']">
...
</xsl:template>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xsd:` in that attribute value isn't a namespace declaration; it's just part of the value of the attribute; you just need `@type = 'xsd:string'` to match it.

EDIT: As per comments, to match anything beginning `xsd:`, you can just use `substring-before(@type,':') = 'xsd'` or `substring(@type,1,4) = 'xsd:'`

Comment: I need to match other xsd types besides xsd:string

Comment: answer is 
<xsl:template match="*[substring-before(@type,':')='xsd']">
your comment helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 transformation, if the type attribute is declared in the schema with type xs:QName, then you want `*[namespace-uri-from-QName(@type) = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema']`

Answer (score 0):

In XPath an unprefixed attribute name is always considered to be in "no namespace".

**So, the `type` attribute is in no namespace.**

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@type = 'xsd:string']">
...
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, the above match pattern matches not only the `identityID` element, but *any* element the string value of whose `type` attribute is `'xsd:string'`.

**UPDATE**: The OP has "admitted in a comment" that he actually needs to match any element whose `type` attribute specifies a name in the XML Schema namespace.

**Here is a correct solution** (the OP's solution only works for a fixed prefix):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[namespace::*
        [name() = substring-before(../@type, ':')
       and
         . = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
         ]
    ]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this transformation matches any element whose `type` attribute's value is a name in the XML schema namespace -- **regardless of the prefix used**!

**When applied, for example, on the following XML document**:

```
<t xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <enitityID maxOccurs="0" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
 <somethingElse/>
 <intIdID maxOccurs="0" minOccurs="0" type="xs:integer"/>
</t>
```

**the correct result (all such matched elements copied to the output) is produced**:

```
<enitityID xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            maxOccurs="0" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>


<intIdID xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         maxOccurs="0" minOccurs="0" type="xs:integer"/>
```

Comment: I need to match other xsd types besides xsd:string

Comment: @bretter: Learn to say what you need in the question!

Comment: @bretter: And see my update for the correct solution to your real problem.